# show man pages in terminal without a pager

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, man

`man` defaults to using a pager. For short pages, I want to just echo them to the terminal without paging. I'm on OS X. Things I've tried:

```
man -t man                  #produces PostScript output
man man | groff -T latin1   #readable, but line wraps badly
man man | troff -a          #readable, but ... interesting ...
man man | echo              #no output
```

Better offers?

Comment: you can try setting `MANPAGER=` (ie empty) in the env.

Comment: At least on OS X that results in an error message when you try to man something

Comment: sorry, dont have an OS X to try it on. Perhaps `MANPAGER=cat` ?

Comment: Yes, that worked. For my needs though, Arjan's answer is good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't get formatting, but you can set the pager to be simply `cat`:

```
man man -P cat
```

Also, `man` won't format when piped, which is why the following gets you the same result:

```
man man | cat
```

Comment: Perfect, dankuwel!

Comment: So that got me to `function mann { man $@ | ul ; }` in my profile

Answer (score 3):

To expand on on [Arjan's Answer](https://superuser.com/a/972045/84853), you can get formatting using cat as a pager if you pipe it to `ul`:

```
man foo -P cat | ul
```

Answer (score 3):

I fact I went a different route because I realised my 'real problem' was with `less` clearing the screen on exit. I put

```
export MANPAGER='/usr/bin/less -isXF'
```

in my startup profile. The `-X` parameter means that when I quit less, whatever part of the man page was on screen, stays there.